# Triangle waveform verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to get a triangle waveform, but my code doesn't work! I think the "if conditions" are organised wrong but I can't find the mistake My wave goes up like it should be and it falls down by 90° after achieving the top

```
  module pila(clk,res,out2);
  input  clk,res;
  output [0:7]out2;
  reg [0:7]out2;
 always @(posedge clk)
 begin
 if (res)
 begin
 if(out2<=8'b11111111)
 out2=out2+1;
 else if(out2>=8'b00000000)
 out2=out2-1;
 else out2=8'b00000000;
 end
 else out2=8'b00000000;
 end
endmodule

module testbench;
reg clk,res;
wire [0:7]out2;
pila Sevo(clk,res,out2);
always #2 clk=~clk;
initial
begin
clk=0;res=0;
#2 res=1;
end
initial #5000 $finish;
endmodule
```

Comment: Your seeing `out2` follow a `00->01->...->FE->FF->00->01->..` pattern but expecting  `00->01->...->FE->FF->FE->..01->00->01->..`, correct?

Comment: @Greg - Yes you're correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some signal to indicate which direction you are currently counting.  Also use the non-blocking assignment operator `<=` rather than the blocking assignment operator `=`.

```
module pila(clk,res,out2);
input  clk,res;
output [0:7]out2;
reg [0:7]out2 = 8'h00;
reg count_down = 1'b0;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
if (count_down == 1'b0)
begin
  if (out2==8'b11111111) // check for top of count
  begin
    count_down <= 1'b1;
    out2<=out2-1;
  end
  else 
    out2<=out2+1; 
end
else 
begin
  if(out2==8'b00000000) // check for bottom of count
   begin
    count_down <= 1'b0;
    out2<=out2+1;
  end
  else 
    out2<=out2-1; 
end
end 
endmodule
```

Comment: Ive got an syntax error atif (out2=8'b11111111), it should be if (out2==8'b11111111), but it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `if(out2<=8'b11111111)` condition is always evaluating to true. This is because `out2` range is 0 to 255. Try adding another flop to control the direction, for example `downup` where 1 means decrement and 0 means increment.

```
if (out2 == 8'h00) begin
  downup <= 1'b0; // up
  out2 <= 8'h01;
end
else if (out2 == 8'hFF) begin
  downup <= 1'b1; // down
  out2 <= 8'hFE;
end
else if (downup) begin // down
  out2 <= out2 - 1;
end
else begin // up
  out2 <= out2 + 1;
end
```

Other issues:

- Use non-blocking assignment (`<=`) for synchronous logic.
- Typically reset (and set) conditions are declared before synchronous logic assignment
- Little-Endian (`[7:0]`)  is more commonly used for packed arrays (previously known as vectors) then Big-Endian (`[0:7]`), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Working example: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4_b

Comment: Your example on edaplayground reverses the order of `out2` and uses `[7:0]` in the module but `[0:7]` in the test bench.